# SSH connections keep dropping

Tags: openssh

I have a server running Ubuntu server 12.0.4 with Openssh-server installed. I can connect to the server for about 30 minutes and then the connection drops. When I try to reconnect I get `The remote system refused the connection.`.

I have used `ps -A | grep ssh` to verify that the the sshd is running, and I can ssh back to 127.0.0.1 and stay connected indefinitely.

I have also tried adding `ClientAliveInterval 60` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check cpu load and memory utilization on server.May be due to high cpu load/memory.You are facing this problem.You can use `free` `uptime` `vmstat` `top` and others tools to figure it out and also check `tail -40 /var/log/auth.log` for more info.

Comment: I did some digging... I found that the processes for my connections were still running, and once these were killed, I could SSH back in to the server.

Comment: The server memory load is at 3%